# Contents of page moves down when lightbox content opens - jquery

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

When the link to my lightbox is clicked on - it moves the contents of the page below the light box.  I have put z-index on css for my lightbox but I believe this isn't enough.  I'm not sure which direction I need to go next.  I am trying to keep the lightbox over top of the page content.  I don't want the content on the page to move down, I would like the lightbox to overlay the original page's content.

**My Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/stillb4llin/zZvLG/

I would think I need to create another function in jquery to insert into where I have put positionLightBox1(); (commented out)

I also think I'm doing the CSS wrong.  I'd like to believe I have a firm grasp on css, but I'm sure you won't!

> **Experience with jquery:** I've been playing with jquery for a few weeks
> (editing code and making it work for me) and I've done some reading
> and have created a few fiddles.  Right now I've felt comfortable
> enough to create this with the help of some of my experience and some
> stack overflow answers.

*Your comments are appreciated.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make position:absolute on #lightBoxContent instead of position:relative

http://jsfiddle.net/zZvLG/9/

...this removes the lightbox from "the flow" and prevents it from pushing the other page contents further down.

Comment: like I said... think I have a grasp on css.  Thank you very much, this worked well

Answer (score 1):

`<div ID="lightBoxDiv"></div>` Why do you close it right after opening? I guess you meant to close if after closing the lightBoxContent div?

Comment: I closed the original div so that I could have the light box itself scroll further down the page, and then I would be working on making the background scroll down further.

The actual page I am working on has a lot more content then what is in the fiddle.

That does work, but I need to play around with it more to see if I can make it work in my situation.

Comment: This worked, however after I transfered this over to the actual site, and adding the background that scrolled, it made it messy, visually.  Otherwise, this was a good answer, just not for my situation

Answer (score 1):

lightBoxContent must have also position:absolute to function properly

Answer (score 1):

just move the  tag at the end of the lightboxdiv declaration to after the closing of the lightboxcontentdiv. You might have to resize a bit, but it won't move the text behind it.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrMiracle/zZvLG/16/

Comment: This worked, however after I transfered this over to the actual site, and adding the background that scrolled, it made it messy, visually.  Otherwise, this was a good answer, just not for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

might fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/zZvLG/14/

Comment: Please explain what you did, changed the html?

Comment: I think he moved the first closed div to the bottom

Comment: Can you try to explain your answer?